# Questions about select-keys function

Tags: clojure

Ideally,select-keys returns a map with keys in the order of the key seq vector. But I find that it happens only when the number of your keys is less than 10

```
(def params {:resource-total-calls-abandoned 1, :resource-idle-time 5, :date "2016-12-31", :resource-wrap-up-time 1, :agent-talk-time 1, :resource-work-offers 3, :aux-in-time 1, :user-id 2183, :resource-not-ready-time 3, :split 1, :aux-out-time 1, :resource-logged-in-time 1, :hold-time 115, :acd-calls 1})

(select-keys  params [:user-id
                                            :date
                                            :split
                                            :resource-logged-in-time
                                            :agent-talk-time
                                            :resource-wrap-up-time
                                            :hold-time
                                            :acd-calls
                                            :resource-total-calls-abandoned

                                            ])
```

Here is my result:

```
{:user-id 2183, :date "2016-12-31", :split 1, :resource-logged-in-time 1, :agent-talk-time 1, :resource-wrap-up-time 1, :hold-time 115, :acd-calls 1, :resource-total-calls-abandoned 1}
```

If I have more than 10 keys  to be selected from a huge map  , the order of the map will be different from the order of keys

```
(select-keys  params [:user-id
                                            :date
                                            :split
                                            :resource-logged-in-time
                                            :agent-talk-time
                                            :resource-wrap-up-time
                                            :hold-time
                                            :acd-calls
                                            :resource-total-calls-abandoned
                                            :aux-in-time
                                            ])
```

The result will be different :

```
{:resource-total-calls-abandoned 1, :date "2016-12-31", :resource-wrap-up-time 1, :agent-talk-time 1, :aux-in-time 1, :user-id 2183, :split 1, :resource-logged-in-time 1, :hold-time 115, :acd-calls 1}
```

Any other ideas about returning  a map with keys in the order of the keyseq vector no matter how many keys you want to select  ?

Comment: Maps are not ordered.  They appear ordered up to 8 entries, but this is an implementation detail, you should never rely on.

Comment: Looks that way . Thanks

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer but just throwing out a quick idea: you could write a function/macro which takes the keyseq and builds a comparator based on its ordering, and then return a sorted map based on that comparator. And yes, if you look at maps less than 9 k/v pairs, you will see the type is `PersistentArrayMap`, and for greater, it's `PersistentHashMap` -- this is the reason for the appearance of ordering, and this is done since hashing will be quicker for large maps, and an array-based implementation is more performant for very small maps.

Comment: @Josh Incidentally this already exists in my [useful](https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/map.clj#L243-L256) library.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an associative structure with order, there is a `sorted-map` that maintains the order of its elements. An off-the-cuff solution could be to first select the keys that you want, and then put them in a new sorted map.

```
(def k [:user-id
        :date
        :split
        :resource-logged-in-time
        :agent-talk-time
        :resource-wrap-up-time
        :hold-time
        :acd-calls
        :resource-total-calls-abandoned
        :aux-in-time])

(->> (select-keys params k)
     (into (sorted-map-by #(< (.indexOf k %1) (.indexOf k %2)))))
```

The comparator function `#(< ...` above is just an example; if you create a sorted map this way, updates to it (e.g., `assoc`) will most definitely do the wrong thing. The reason is that the index in vector `k` is used to compare the order of elements, but it is -1 for any element not in the vector.

A more efficient solution could be to *reduce* over the map into a sorted data structure.

*Update:* As suggested by @leetwinski, changed `apply` to `into`, which removes the need to flatten the map after `select-keys`.

Comment: Interesting idea, I like it!

Comment: can be simplified like this: `(->> (select-keys params k) (into (sorted-map-by #(< (.indexOf k %1) (.indexOf k %2)))))` . Using `into` instead of `apply` would eliminate the need to flatten the selected keys map

Comment: @leetwinski Thanks! I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome  .  A great idea